# Lucene.net issue

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I have an issue with Lucene.net (rel 4.8.0-beta00016). I'm not quite clear on the difference between creating an index and opening it later to add documents. I've created a C# application - using framework version 4.7.2 - in which I have a method CreateIndex() written as follows:

```
public void CreateIndex()
{
    var Dir = FSDirectory.Open(this.IndexPathName); // Property IndexPathName contains the path that contains index
    var Analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(AppLuceneVersion);
    var indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(AppLuceneVersion, Analyzer);
    this.iIndexWriter = new IndexWriter(Dir, indexConfig); 
}
```

If, after calling `CreateIndex()`, I add documents to the index, everything works. The problem arises when I close the app. When I relaunch it to add more files, if I invoke `CreateIndex()`, the index files get overwritten.

What code do I need to implement to open an existing index for adding documents?

Comment: Try changing `new IndexWriter(Dir, indexConfig);` to `new IndexWriter(Dir, indexConfig, false);`

Comment: the constructor doesn't accept 3 arguments...

Answer (score 0):

While there may be others, there are generally 2 common strategies for using Lucene.NET:

1. Create the index during build/deploy, and use `IndexReader` during application use to do searches.
2. Use a Near Real-Time search strategy. This means your application will open a singleton instance of `IndexWriter`. To read, you would call `IndexWriter.GetReader()`. And you can use the singleton instance of `IndexWriter` to add/delete/update documents at runtime at the same time reads are happening.

I suggest also looking at the [tutorial](https://lucenenet.apache.org/quick-start/tutorial.html) and the demos for [creating an index](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/Lucene.Net_4_8_0_beta00016/src/Lucene.Net.Demo/IndexFiles.cs) and [searching an index](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/Lucene.Net_4_8_0_beta00016/src/Lucene.Net.Demo/SearchFiles.cs) to get started.